# Headless Chrome runs forever

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-headless

I'm using `chrome-remote-interface` to run chrome in the headless mode and I have some issues with navigating to this page https://www.gsksaglik.com/internal-redirects.html.

The problem is that I don't get any new requests and it runs forever because it doesn't fires the `loadEventFired` event

This is my code:

```
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');
CDP((client) => {
    // extract domains
    const {Network, Page} = client;
    // setup handlers
    Network.requestWillBeSent((params) => {
        console.log(params.request.url);
    });
    Page.loadEventFired(() => {
        client.close();
    });
    // enable events then start!
    Promise.all([
        Network.enable(),
        Page.enable()
    ]).then(() => {
        return Page.navigate({url: 'https://www.gsksaglik.com/internal-redirects.html'});
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        client.close();
    });
}).on('error', (err) => {
    // cannot connect to the remote endpoint
    console.error(err);
});
```

Please let me know if I need to provide more details